# Persist autocmd per file (not per filetype) without vimrc

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I have some autocmd triggering on `TextChanged`, that I want to have persisted between Vim restarts.

I could make a big if-elseif construct in the vimrc, sure, but I prefer saving the autocmd only for the specific file, as the autocmd cmd changes with each file.

Can this be done using view sessions? Do you have better ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In your `~/.vimrc`, you can define an `:autocmd` that targets the opening of the particular file, and then define the `TextChanged` autocmd for the particular buffer in there:

```
autocmd BufRead /path/to/the/special/file autocmd TextChanged <buffer> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods I can think of are:

- initiating vim with a `-u filename.vimrc` for each file you want to specify the modifications with, and have *it* source your primary `.vimrc` to bring in the rest of your normal work environment.
- creating a separate autocmd file for specific subset paths or files, then `source`ing that from your main `.vimrc`

For the external `autuocmd` file:

```
augroup the_file_types
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost my.fun.file call MyFunction('arg1')
augroup END
autocmd BufWrite my.other.file do_something_else
```

The first sounds annoying to me to have to remember every time I start up the editor; the second is more versatile and less harrying.